# Getting package/application info programmatically from Google Store without installing the app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

don't know if possible, but i'll try.
My goal is to retrieve some app information (e.g. version, signatures/permissions) from an app on google store, without installing it.
In other words, there is a way to get a file with android market app's info?
Otherwise, can i download it programmatically from store without installing it? (so i can easily retrieve the infromations i need)
For example i need to input a package name and my app should give me information, taken from market, of this app.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Chrome Webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) but it only allows you to get information about the apps that you own.